# Why do I get the error "bash: ./a.out: Permission denied" when I execute a C program in Linux mint 15

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a user `ls` command code in C. When I compile this code with `cc lss.c`, an `a.out` file is created, but then using `./a.out` to run, I get an error.

My `lss.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cmdline[100];
    if ( argc > 2 )
    {
        printf(cmdline, "ls %s %s", argv[1], argv[2]);
        system(cmdline);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run, this is what happens:

```
$ cd "/media/dilip/New Volume1/c"
$ cc lss.c
$ ./a.out
bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
$
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: You need to have execution permissions for this file. `chmod +x a.out` should solve it.

Comment: Looks like the filesystem was mounted incorrectly.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail/

Comment: Your code should be calling `sprintf()` rather than `printf()`, and preferably `snprintf()` with other changes to check that you don't get attacked (stack overflow) by over-long command line arguments.  However, this is somewhat tangential to the 'cannot execute' problem.  Have you checked the permissions on `a.out`?  By default, the execute bit would be set.  What's your `umask` value set to?

Comment: @glglgl: your edit is nice except that it loses one critical piece of information — the current directory embedded in the prompt.  That directory was `/media/dilip/New Volume1/c`, which lends credence to the suggestion that an NTFS partition is involved.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `mount | grep 'media/dilip/New Volume 1'` and `ls -l '/media/dilip/New Volume1/c/a.out'`, so we can make sure it's a mount problem.

Comment: @Pikrass http://i.imgur.com/OqXtugu.png?1 
is it a mount problem?

Comment: Oops, the grep was too restrictive. Run `mount` and show us the line concerning the file system where your `a.out` is.

Answer (score 5):

I think, you are trying to run your program on an NTFS partition, different from the one on which Mint is installed. Try to compile the program in your ext4 partition and generate the a.out there. It should run.

Comment: The other alternative would be to remount the partition to allow setting the execute bit.

Comment: Compiling on another partition wouldn't change anything, it's only a matter of permissions. But you're probably right, the partition must have been mounted with `noexec` or something alike.

Comment: Yes, its probably mounted with noexec. I only suggested the quicker way.

Comment: @kunal what is NTFS ? And how to compile the program in ext4 partition?

Comment: @Pikrass how do i mount it?

Answer (score 0):

Compile and Run it on the Volume where your linux is installed.